# Maven Workspace and System Dependencies Missing in JAR Manifest

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, system, manifest

My project depends on "mssql-jdbc".
Because this lib isn't in the public repository I add "mssql-jdbc" as a system dependency. When I run the app out of eclipse, everything is fine.

But now I want to create a jar (jar:jar) for distribution. But "mssql-jdbc" and another lib from the workspace are not mentioned in the classpath of the JARs manifest.

I try to solve this issue for several weeks and it freaking me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By making it a dependency in the `system` scope you are telling Maven not to include it.  Per [docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope):

> The artifact is always available and is not looked up in a repository

This is typically used for things that are provided by the VM.  Again, the [docs provide helpful tips](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies).

What you need to do is to [make it available in your repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) and then use it like a normal JAR dependency.

Comment: Okay that make sense BUT my own lib is missing too! It's another Maven-Eclipse Project in the same workspace.

Comment: What do you mean "my own lib"?  Is this a JAR that you express as a dependency?  If so, what scope are you using for _it_?

Comment: I have two Projects "foo-lib" and "bar-app". Both are Maven-Eclipse Projects.

"bar-app" needs "foo-lib". Inside Eclipse it works. But jar:jar for "bar-app" do not add "foo-lib" to the classpath. Okay maven do not know where the jar is, but it is not practicable to import the "foo-lib".jar always manually to the local maven repro.

Comment: I suggest that you use `mvn install` to install foo-lib.jar to your local repository.  Then state foo-lib.jar as a dependency in `bar-app`'s POM.

Comment: This seems to work, thanks. So I install/deploy `foo-lib` always after I run `jar:jar`. To do this automatically I add this to the goal in Eclipse.

I'm THE developer of `foo-lib`, but some co-workers use my lib, so it's not a real solution. I would like to install/deploy the jar to a directory on an network drive. Have you an idea how I can force maven in eclipse to use the public repo AND this folder on an network drive?

Comment: To install to your local repository (the one in your home directory) you use the `mvn install` command.  To share it with your team what you have to do is "deploy" it.  As you may have guessed you have to invoke `mvn deploy`.  This will automatically run the `install` phase as well.  However you have to _tell_ Maven **where** to deploy your JAR.  You describe this via the distributionManagement element (http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management).